# How to Apply join in sequelize

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

```
           s.uid,
           s.NAME u.NAME as fname
FROM       users
INNER JOIN s
ON         s.uid = u.id
WHERE      s.cid = 300;
```

**I want to convert the raw query into sequelize query**

Answer (score 0):

Join is simple when using sequelize. you need to use the paramter

```
include:[]
```

inorder to perform inner join, you just need to pass a parameter

```
required: true
```

in the query.

for your raw query, the sequelize query will be like

```
let data = await db.models.users.findAll({
             attributes: ['NAME'],
             include: [
                        {
                           model: 's',
                           as: 's',
                           where: {cid: 300},
                           attributes: ['uid', 'name'],
                           required: true
                         }
                       ]
                  })
```